# Implementing .NET SHA1 password validation in JAVA

Tags: java, asp.net, hash, passwords, sha1

I need help in implementing a password authentication function in JAVA (1.6), where the data originated in .NET.

Background: in the project, we are migrating data from the customer's old system to the new system. Part of the data is the hashed passwords and salts of the users.

So I have a hashed password and a salt, both as Strings.

According to the customer, the password hashes were created using "standard .NET SHA1 encryption".

I have found code detailing what .NET does (including base64-ing etc) but no code in JAVA which will validate a password given the salt and the expected hash.

Needless to say, my trials were not successful.

Can you help?

To elaborate:

I need a function 'hashPasswordLikeNET' which will do this for me:

```
String passwordHash = hashPasswordLikeNET( String cleartextPassword, String salt );
boolean isValid = passwordHash.equals( storedPasswordHash );
```

What is not necessary is generating a new hash/salt for a new password - if a user changes his password in the new system, it will be encoded using a different algorithm (and validated according to that algorithm subsequently).

When I'm back at work tomorrow I'll add a sample password / salt / hash provided by the customer as well as a snippet of my code so far.

Thanks!

Neil

============ Additional detail ==============

Our customer has given us the task of importing his current user base, including the passwords. These are stored as hash/salt combinations.

So I need to be able to validate the password the user types in when logging in against the stored hash value, using the customer's 'algorithm' re-implemented in JAVA. This algorithm is, according to the customer, 'standard ASP.NET SHA1'.

I have been given, as an example, the following:

- Password: 12345!
- Hash: UDRc2nvL4AGLL90xOzxg4PT3oqA=
- Salt: NJC5qJDJ8kh73jrPO+Z0zg==

I.e. I need to do some magic to make password * salt = hash in JAVA.

My code so far:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


String createHashLikeNET( String password, String salt ) throws PasswordServiceException
{
    try
    {
        Mac sha1_HMAC = Mac.getInstance( "HmacSHA1" );
        sha1_HMAC.init( new SecretKeySpec( salt.getBytes( "UTF-8" ), "HmacSHA1" ) );

        byte[] hashedBytes = sha1_HMAC.doFinal( password.getBytes( "UTF-8" ) );

        return Base64.encodeBase64String( hashedBytes );
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        throw new PasswordServiceException(e);
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e)
    {
        throw new PasswordServiceException(e);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        throw new PasswordServiceException(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String expectedHash = "UDRc2nvL4AGLL90xOzxg4PT3oqA=";
    String calculatedHash = createHashLikeNET( "12345!", "NJC5qJDJ8kh73jrPO+Z0zg==" );
    System.out.println( "Expected: " + expectedHash + ", result: " + calculatedHash );
}
```

However I tweak my code, I don't get the required result.

Also, can anyone validate that the example given to me by the customer actually works in .NET?

Comment: Uh not entirely sure what the problem is here. MessageDigest can create the hash, sha1 is supported by default so... What exactly more do you need?

Comment: Please provide more detail, like an example of how you currently do hashing in C# and in Java.

Comment: I recently came across [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) which took away all my encryption headaches.